# Document4j support for other ms word like applications

Tags: documents4j

I want to convert ms office documents to pdf. I thought of using document4j for that. But I could see that we need msoffice setup to make it work. Can we somehow use open-office or other libre-office for doing the same work. MSOffice cost is much high so want to use something open-source.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own converter by [implementing the `IExternalConverter` API](https://github.com/documents4j/documents4j/blob/master/documents4j-transformer-api/src/main/java/com/documents4j/conversion/IExternalConverter.java). You could for example delegate to Open Office. No such implementation exists currently but by implementing the interface, you can activate the API and use all of documents4j client and server implementations.